VBA Userform - How to manage semi-frequent column adds/deletes to data worksheet
I'm still very new to VBA. I have a userform that I use to populate a data worksheet that has 100+ columns. Due to process changes and being given additional responsibilities, I find myself adding/deleting columns (fields) in the worksheet to accommodate for these changes.
For example, one of our forms has 15 fields (columns) see example below. The form has just been cut down to 11 fields. A few fields were combined into one. Some fields were deleted altogether, plus new fields have been added.
1st & 2nd Shift Rate > Weekday Hours 6 am to 6 pm
3rd Shift Rate > Sat. & Off Shift Hours 6 pm to 6 am
Sat, Sun, Hol Rate > Sunday & Holiday Hours
Add Overtime Rate 
Travel < 8 Hrs Rate - Combined A
Travel > 8 Hrs Rate - Combined A
Airfare > No change
Hotel > Combined B
Car Rental > Combined C
Meals > Combined B
Mileage > Combined C
Parking > Combined C
Service Parts1 > No Change
Service Parts2 > Delete
Booking Fees > Delete
Lab Usage Daily Rate > Add New
Lab Set Up > Add New

As if the change isn't a big enough job. I'm not sure what to do about the existing orders that have data from the older form. I don't want to delete it. I can concatenate the combined fields, but that doesn't help with the rest.
I would appreciate any expert's insight. I want to understand the options before I tackle this.
